# Server-error when DriveApp.getFolderById try to get (bigger) folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm automating folder-creation for both projets and customers. The customer-folder has ~400 sub-folders and throws the same error. Exception: a servererror occured. wait and try again later *(translated)*

```
function test () {
  DriveApp.getFolderById("28letterFolderIdxxxxxxxxxxxx")
}
```

The Apps Script is unable to access the main folder. It fails before doing anything fancy. I've tried multiple account; incl. owner.
I did a migrate a few folders (many hours prior) but are now starting to suspect that it's the size (360+ subfolder) that is the problem.

- Drive-api works fine (get folder)
- Same function (copy/paste) works in new script-file

Can script-files get corrupted? I rather not remake it, as it's a library, in use.

Comment: Create a copy of your spreadsheet the script is attached to and run the script from there. It is not a solution but rather a workaround that could work .

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Script had a connected GCP-project where the Drive-scope hadn't been added. It also needed to be reinstalled.